# how to display a pdf in django admin? instead of the link

Tags: django, django-admin

models.py

```
class Equipo(models.Model):
    CODIGO = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5 )
    DESCRIPCION = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    TITULO = models.FileField(upload_to = "Archivos/Titulos/", default='', blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Equipo

class EquipoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('CODIGO', 'DESCRIPCION', 'TITULO')
admin.site.register(Equipo, EquipoAdmin)
```

I need to see something like this

[image: I need to see something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82yG8.png)

```
# admin.py
list_display = ('title', 'description', 'embed_pdf', 'deadline')

def embed_pdf(self, obj):
    try:
        html = f'<iframe src="{obj.add_file.url}" width="200px" height="200px" frameborder="2"></iframe>'
        formatted_html = format_html(html.format(url=obj.add_file.url))
        return formatted_html
    except Exception as e:
        pass

embed_pdf.short_description = "File/Image"
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```